# What tools allow me to create semi-transparent overlays on top of other windows?

Tags: overlay

I am looking to add some information to the screen over top of windows in the form of semi-transparent borderless elements. I have some familiarity with PyGame and thought that might work well but it appears that the library it is built on does not allow for consistently transparent windows. There may also be a need to do some 3d elements or animation on screen so I looked at Unity3d for this but I do not see any info online about making the game window transparent--instead I see info about making transparent gui elements or glass windows in the game.

Long term the intention is to allow overlay of fullscreen applications like games which I know can be problematic so right now I just want to focus on windowed elements.

Any suggestions for a tool or platform that would meet these requirements or know if and how PyGame or Unity could be used to meet my needs? What about a way to have a borderless and transparent Chrome browser window so then I can use something like canvas or webgl?

Comment: I think you are trying to address a problem which is really OS dependent... What about trying some frameworks like Qt or JavaFX or GTK?

Comment: Yeah, for my proof-of-concept I have come to the conclusion that I will use Python with wxPython which can do borderless, transparent windows. I did looked at PyQt as well. I would not be surprised if can't work over top of a fullscreen application but getting such a feature going will be the second milestone in the dev process. For the moment I am satisfied so will post an answer to that affect as it does answer my primary concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that wxPython supports borderless, transparent windows so it will fit my needs for creating proof-of-concept.